# Xcode build error on simulator clang: error: no such file or directory: '__entitlements'

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode8

I have a react native app with Pods included. It works and runs fine on actual device, but recently when I try to run it on Simulator, I get this weird error `clang: error: no such file or directory: '__entitlements'`.

Any ideas what could be causing it?

Comment: can you look in both your Xcode project file inspector and your project settings for the `__entititlements` file and tell me where it's found?

Comment: I do have a `MobileApp.entitlements` with location relative to group as `MobileApp/MobileApp.entitlements`. It's content is pretty much `<key>aps-environment</key><string>development</string>` only.

Comment: Were you able to sort this? I am running into the same issue, only when targeting the simulator.

Answer (score 14):

I was running into this issue and I figured out a solution. In my specific instance I had a wayward `-force_load` argument in the 'additional linker flags' without a path specified. I believe this was causing some arguments to become out of place with the linking. Once I removed this, the error stopped.

Comment: This is exactly what I had - I'd been "tidying" a particular unused path out of the "Other Linker Flags" and has missed the "-force_load" for one of the targets. So glad you wrote this answer!

Comment: Yep.  Me too, but in my case, it was a stray `-B`

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, I had this in the Build Settings in Other Linker Flag

```
Other Linker Flag = (
                "$(inherited)",
                "-ObjC",
                "-force_load",
            );
```

remove `-force_load`.Then Clean and Build your Project and then try again.